# ColorBox Frame not Visible in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, transparency, colorbox

Live Example:
https://www.702wedding.com/live/

I am using Colorbox, and it works perfect for all my browsers except Internet Explorer. BOTH the outside modal FRAME AND the .txt include FOOTER text are displaying incorrectly. The Modal FRAME, I think has something to do with the transparency. The .txt footer include text is ALL bold, and should not be, thats something that is a mystery to me.

Thanks for Your Time Friends.
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The footer text looks the same in IE7/8 as it does in Firefox, so I can't help with that:

[image] ***(in IE8)***

The border problem is caused by your eight lines like this:

```
.cboxIE #cboxTopLeft {
    background:transparent;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader
           (src=images/internet_explorer/borderTopLeft.png, sizingMethod='scale')
}
```

*(I added line breaks just to make it clearer)*

The path for those images is wrong.

Looking at other image paths in your CSS file, you should change the path to, for example:

```
../images/internet_explorer/borderTopLeft.png
```

Make sure you <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for `AlphaImageLoader`, and fix all instances of the problem.

Comment: I have done what you have suggested, but I am not showing it fixed on my screen. What have I done wrong? I changed the image path like you have noted, but I am having issues. Have a moment to take a second look? Always Appreciated.

Comment: It looks fixed for me: [screenshot of IE8](http://i.imgur.com/xHC8Z.png). What version of IE are you testing with?

Comment: Works Perfect. Thank You. I was using Browser shots to See, my PC just went down yesterday and I am using a. . . mac.

Answer (score 1):

It states very clearly in the Colorbox CSS file that the Internet Explorer 6 & 7 paths at the end need to be relative to the page from which the script is being run. `"../"` is absolutely no good. Stick the full path in it, if you are using WordPress, good luck!

Comment: Could you indicate where in the CSS file it says that, perhaps by quoting the relevant section?